# gh-pages, Landing page

Tags: url, github-pages

Can we set a Landing page by a name other than `index.html` or a different path . I tried and it dint work. Searched and din't get any relevant solution, I am not using Jekyll or other template engine.

Answer (score 0):

On github Pages the default page served on `domain.tld/` or `domain.tld/any/path/` is `index.html`.

There's not setup available to change that.

Comment: I'm really curious about this downvote. Is my answer correct ? Yes. Is there any documentation about this ? No. What else ?

Comment: The answer is really convincing, I dint get much of info after searching, But i donno who and why its downvoted